# TYPO3 RealUrl Conf - Access ext field

Tags: typo3, realurl

Is it possible to make my Url like this?

http://xx.de/projects/xxx/suche/dentist/city/

I have an powermail form, with this form a user can search for entries in our database. If the user search only with the cityname, the name have to show in the url (instead of city above).

Can I access in realurl conf to the post var???

Comment: Please edit your question and figure out what you are trying to archieve. Please also provide some code snippets if possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can install EXT:realurl and use the following to shape your url exactly as you want with `typo3conf/realurl_conf.php`:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array (
    'encodeSpURL_postProc' => array('user_encodeSpURL_postProc'),
    'decodeSpURL_preProc' => array('user_decodeSpURL_preProc'),
    '_DEFAULT' => array (
    ...

    USUAL CONFIGURATION

    ...
    ),
);

function user_encodeSpURL_postProc(&$params, &$ref) {
    $params['URL'] = str_replace('url-entry-given/', 'projects/xxx/suche/dentist/city/', $params['URL']);
}
function user_decodeSpURL_preProc(&$params, &$ref) {
    $params['URL'] = str_replace('projects/xxx/suche/dentist/city/', 'url-entry-given/', $params['URL']);
}
```

you cannot manipulate your domain this way though.

And I hope you don't need a massive list of definitions, and I hope the `url-entry-given` has a distinct value for the cityname ...